# ffmpeg scaled output resolution is off by 1px for non-standard inputs

Tags: ffmpeg, video, resolution

I'm using the `ffmpeg` CLI to scale user-submitted videos:

```
ffmpeg -i path/to/file -vf scale=1920:-2 -c:v libx264 -r 30 output.mp4
```

The scaling works fine with standard video sizes, such as `1920×1080` and `720×480`. However, once we start using videos that do *not* have conventional resolutions, the output begins to scale incorrectly.

For example, a video that has a resolution of `3360×1882` will output to `1921×1076`, when the expected resolution *should* theoretically be: `1920×1075`.

Now, obviously `ffmpeg` is attempting to account for that remaining `.42857px` on the height, but I'd prefer it just get cropped off instead (doesn't matter if it's from the top or bottom).

How would I go about doing this *safely* for every video?

**For bonus points,** how do I make it swap scaling depending on if the `height` is greater than the `width` (and vice versa). For example, if the video has a ratio of `2:1`, it scales using a height of `1080px` instead of a width of `1920px`.

Comment: How are you checking the output resolution?

Comment: @Gyan Mac's "Get Info"

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/39088158/